# How to transform a column into an array using ADF

Tags: database, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to read a column on a db on ADF and use all it´s values as parameters in a foreach.

I tried reading the column using a dataflow and a cache sink to then in a pipeline use Set Variable and then the foreach...but instead of an array of values I get an array with one value that contains all the others I want (but i cant iterate over)
I am using:
`@array(activity('myDataflow').output.runStatus.output.columName`

Any help is appreciated, seems simple enough (column to array) but I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup activity to get the data from SQL server, and run for each loop on the output of the lookup.
Example:

1. Create a new pipeline
2. Add a lookup activity
3. Choose your source dataset (in this example, an Azure SQL database)
4. Remove the checkbox from “First row only”
5. Choose a table, stored procedure or type in a query

   SELECT 1 AS result UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 AS result UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 AS result UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 AS result
   [image: lookup activity]
6. Add a foreach activity
7. In the foreach activity, under settings tab: “Items” -
   @activity('Lookup SQL query').output.value – where 'Lookup SQL
   query' is the name of the lookup activity
   [image: for each activity]
8. Inside the foreach loop, add a wait activity
9. In the settings tab, “Wait time in seconds” : @item().result .
   item() is the current loop, and result is the name of the SQL column
   [image: wait activity]

debug the pipeline. You can see that the foreach activity iterates 4 times, for every row returned from the sql query.
[image: lookup activity results]

Comment: Do u have an example of that? I fail to see how the lookup would help on grabbing the whole column

Comment: I edited my answer to add an example with screenshots. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use append variable activity also, inside **ForEach** after lookup.

First create an array variable in the pipeline.

[image]

Then use append variable activity inside ForEach and give

```
@item.<your_column_name>
```

[image]

Result variable stored in a sample variable:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

> I tried reading the column using a dataflow and a cache sink to then in a pipeline use Set Variable and then the foreach

If you want to do it with dataflows instead of lookup, use the same above procedure and give the below dynamic content in the ForEach.

`@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value`

[image]